# Rails Active Admin: How to display index page of one resource inside a show page of other resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

In my Rails application I have, for an example, models Client and Service, with an association one to many. I've registered Client as a resource in active admin, but I don't want to create separate index page for Services. I want to be able to view services that belong to client at the client's show page, but I want services list look like as it would be displayed at the own index page: as table with sortable columns etc. Something like at the image below:

[image]

The client details part is rendered via partial.

Comment: So, what the problem? When you show Client page, get all his Services and display them in the table.

Comment: I want this table look like default activeadmin, and be able to sort by columns

Comment: Even now, I believe there's only a way to include services as nested resources of client listed as a table like http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html#nested-resources docs said. good luck.

Comment: Did that help or do you need more assistance?

Comment: @BenNelson 3 years have passed already :) I think I found some solution that time ago.

Comment: just scouring unanswered questions for upvotes man! :)

Comment: @VadymKovalenko if you found an answer to your question, answer it or delete it.

Comment: @VadymKovalenko plese tell me what you did use to get those tabs?

Answer (score 0):

The sorting functionality is provided by an [Arbre component](http://www.activeadmin.org/docs/12-arbre-components.html) called [IndexAsTable](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/activeadmin/activeadmin/ActiveAdmin/Views/IndexAsTable).  Register the resource ClientService { [belongs_to](http://www.activeadmin.org/docs/2-resource-customization.html) :client }